# Construction with "sein" + infinitive?

Tags: grammar, usage

In Harry Potter, the sentence

> I'll send this with Hedwig when she gets back; she's off hunting at the moment.

is translated as

> Ich schick dir diesen Brief mit Hedwig, sobald sie zurückkommt, im Augenblick ist sie jagen.

What type of construction is "im Augenblick ist sie jagen"?

It is not present tense -- that would be "im Augenblick jagt sie"

It's not a noun phrase either -- that would be something like "im Augenblick ist sie zum Jagen".

Is this construction at all correct?

Comment: Witzig: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absentiv
Aber auch wenn niemand dem einen Namen gegeben hätte, hätte ich es als richtig empfunden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As for the intention of this particular wording (assumed of course):
`Im Augenblick jagt sie` would be
`She's hunting right now` or `At the moment, she is hunting`,
focussing on what she is doing.
The wordings used (in both english and german texts) however want to convey that Hedwig is not present. The reasons for her absence is a side information, which makes the sentence seem more complete and preemtively answers the question "where is she then?".

Carsten Schultz's suggested link [Absentiv](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absentiv) is worth reading.
It explains the construction and usage of these sentences quite well,
along with the reasons they exist.