# "Sein" + infinitive, without "zu"

Tags: colloquial

Similar to "Wir gehen tanzen!", one can say "Wir sind tanzen!".
I have heard this construction often. For example my parents might tell me on the phone: "Wir sind (gerade) spazieren."
It also works in the past tense: "Wir waren tanzen."

As a native speaker I know that the difference between "Wir waren tanzen." and "Wir tanzten." or "Wir haben getanzt." is that the first describes the general evening (including standing in line, talking to people, having an occasional drink), while the second and third only refer to the specific action of dancing.

Now a german-teacher of my wife claims that this construction can only be used in spoken language. This feels wrong to me, but I cannot find the name of this construction, nor can I find the "official" gramar for this.

So: How is this construction called? Where to find "official" gramar for this?

Comment: See https://german.stackexchange.com/search?q=Absentiv, for instance https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/15364/construction-with-sein-infinitive/15368.

Comment: Willkommen! Nur falls Du es nicht weißt: Du kannst hier auch auf Deutsch fragen, es ist ganz Deine Wahl.